# Scraping issues from Tripadvisor

Tags: r, web-scraping, tripadvisor

I am trying to scrap some hotel reviews from TripAdvisor. The code below gives me all the reviews for Giant case hotel reviews from all pages. Yet when I add rate, quoting and rate I get only the first page of reviews. To reiterate, without these 3 items I get all the reviews from 1st page to 60, etc. Can someone help me?

```
#Load library
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)

df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()), File=character(),User=character(), ?stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- 0
for(i in c(1:500)){
url <- ""
if(x == 0){
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g209948-d189773-Reviews-Giant_s_Causeway-Bushmills_County_Antrim_Northern_Ireland.html"
x <- x + 10
 } else{
url <- paste("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g209948-d189773-Reviews-or",x,"-Giant_s_Causeway-Bushmills_County_Antrim_Northern_Ireland.html#REVIEWS", sep = "")
x <- x + 10
 }
   reviews <- url %>%
   read_html() %>%
   html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

   id <- reviews %>%
   html_node(".quote a") %>%
   html_attr("id")

   review <- reviews %>%
   html_node(".entry .partial_entry") %>%
   html_text()


   #quote <- reviews %>%
   #html_node(".quote span") %>%
   #html_text()


   #rating <- reviews %>%
   #html_node(".rating span") %>%
   #html_attr("class") %>%
   #gsub("ui_bubble_rating bubble_", "", .) %>%
   #gsub("0", "", .) %>%
   #as.integer()

   #date <- reviews %>%
   #html_node(".rating .ratingDate") %>%
   #html_attr("title") %>%
   #strptime("%d %b %Y") %>%
   #as.POSIXct()

  if(nrow(df) == 0){
      df <- data.frame(id, review, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  else{
      temp <- df
      df <- rbind(temp, data.frame(id, review, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }
}
```

Comment: To correct, when I add quote, rate and date.

Comment: What language is this? R? Please also use the appropriate tag. Are you aware that TripAdvisor has an API?

Comment: yes, this is RStudio/

Comment: nnnmmm can you please help me what tag I shall put? I am new to stackoverflow. Thank you

Comment: The "r" tag. Also, like I said, have you looked at the TripAdvisor API? Sooms like the sanctioned way to get this data. https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/

Comment: I am not aware of this. Plus, i am quite new to this. Therefore, have not clue of the alternatives rather scraping with the code above. If you do not have an idea of it it is okay. Yet, will look up to see wat is TripAdvisor API and how can be used.